# android Recyclerview removing item does not update adapter's get item count

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with swiping feature to reveal a delete and edit button.

I added: `adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)` and this:
`adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, adapter.getItemCount());`

when the revealed delete button is clicked, the animation for removing the item works and
The item is deleted from my database

BUT then the deleted item re-appears in my recyclerview. When I change activity and go back, to the activity with the recyclerview, the list that I should be seeing is good.

If I remove the "notifyItemRangeChanged" code, the list updates with the last item repeated.

I think it is my Adapter's getItemCount not properly updating. so what I tried differently was to call my method that generates the list in the first place. This did the trick BUT my remove item animation is gone now because I guess it just skips to re-generate the list....

Any ideas?

Thank you in advanced for your feedback!

****************** UPDATE - ADDING ADAPTER CLASS CODE ****************
public class RVCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
        Context context;
        List categoryItemList;

```
    public RVCategoryAdapter(Context context, List<CategoryItem> categoryItemList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.categoryItemList = categoryItemList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.category_item_layout, parent, false);

        return new CategoryViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final int categoryID;
        final String categoryTitle;

        Glide.with(context).load(categoryItemList.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.ivCategoryIcon);
        holder.txtCatID.setText(""+categoryItemList.get(position).getCategoryID());
        holder.txtCategoryTitle.setText(categoryItemList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtCategoryDesc.setText(categoryItemList.get(position).getDescription());

        categoryID = Integer.parseInt(holder.txtCatID.getText().toString());
        categoryTitle = holder.txtCategoryTitle.getText().toString();
        holder.cardViewItemLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotesListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("CategoryID", categoryID);
                intent.putExtra("CategoryTitle", categoryTitle);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryItemList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: you should paste your adapter class

Comment: I edited my post...

Comment: apparently you are not updating your inner ArrayList so getItemCount will always return the same thing. When you want to remove an item from your RecyclerView you have to remove it from your source list.

Comment: @gyosida that is what I was missing! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your swipe delete button click listener remove your item from the list, too.
I would suggest you to add delete function in your adapter. Then in that method delete your item from list and call notifyItemRemoved.

```
public void delete(int position){
    categoryItemList.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```